# PayPal Here Android SDK Error - BadConfiguration: Cannot proceed with this merchant account

Tags: android, xamarin, paypal, paypal-here

I'm trying to integrate the PayPal Here swipers into a Xamarin Android app. Everything is fine until I try and give my credentials to the SDK. Specifically, the line containing the call to `PayPalHereSDK.SetCredentials`

```
public void InitializeSdk( Context context, string serverName, string accessToken, string refreshUrl, string expires, IPayPalHereSdkWrapperCallback listener ) {
        PayPalHereSDK.Init( context, serverName );
        PayPalHereSDK.RegisterAuthenticationListener( this );
        PayPalHereSDK.CardReaderManager.RegisterCardReaderConnectionListener( this );
        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( accessToken ) ) {
            var credentials = new OAuthCredentials( accessToken, refreshUrl, expires );
            PayPalHereSDK.SetCredentials( credentials, new SetAccessTokenResponseHandler( listener ) );
        }
    }
```

My `SetAccessTokenResponseHandler` class implements the `Com.PayPal.Merchant.Sdk.Domain.IDefaultResponseHandler` interface. As described above, the `OnError` function is called when call the `PayPalHereSDK.SetCredentials` function. I'm given the error code "BadConfiguration" and the message "Cannot proceed with this merchant account. ready"

I've searched Google high and low and, I believe, scoured SO pretty thoroughly. I can't seem to overcome the error, so I'm asking for help!

Comment: i have a question, how did you generate refreshUrl? in the iOS repo on github they are hitting some API in their heroku app which i cant do. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly the issue was, but I ended up deleting the Sandbox App in my PayPal dev portal and creating a new one. Everything works now. *head scratch*

I resorted to this because, while trying to follow Sundar's suggestion, I started getting an "invalid scope" error. I had received them before and KNEW I had it fixed ( and no code had changed ). When I deleted/recreated the app, that error went away. Frustrating, but that's what worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think the paypal email is not verified properly. Please go through the merchant onboarding guide document to get more details regarding making the merchant eligible.

https://github.com/paypal/paypal-here-sdk-android-distribution/blob/master/docs/Merchant%20Onboarding%20Guide.pdf

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! I did end up at a solution by following your suggestion. I had went through the Onboarding Guide before, but the one you sent me was a little different, so I figured I'd go through it and see since I wasn't having luck with anything else. What ended up working was deleting and recreating my sandbox app. The PayPal equiv of "turning it off and on again"